# Firebase - different listeners in the same node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the Firebase Web SDK and I have a problem with the duplication of listeners. I tried to create different objects with internal listeners, but sometimes when these objects are equal, and if I remove one listener, the other listener which is equal to the second object is also removed.

I think because it's possible to only have one listener for different node. But in my app, sometimes it is necessary to have equal objects with active or unactive listeners in different moments.

Is there a method to create different listeners in the same node?

my code is this to add a listener

```
firebase.database().ref(path).on('child_added', function (count) {})
```

and this to remove a listener

```
firebase.database().ref(path).off()
```

if i have differents listeners in same node the off function remove all of this listeners. i think is useful a method to understand the id of each listener

Comment: It is definitely possible to have multiple, different listeners on a single node. You forgot to include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that it's hard to say anything.

Comment: sorry i add a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `off()` without any parameters like you do will remove all listeners at that location.

If you want to detach a specific listener, you have to pass in the event type and the callback:

```
var callback = function (count) {...};
firebase.database().ref(path).on('child_added', callback);

...

firebase.database().ref(path).off('child_added', callback);
```